# JavaFx Task EventHandler handled in which Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, task, javafx-8

For JavaFX UI node, if I register an event handler:

```
final MenuItem buyItem = new MenuItem("Buy");

buyItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        String symbol = row.getItem().getSymbol();
        String instrumentID = row.getItem().getInstrumentID();
        .....
    }
);
```

I can assume code inside `handle()` will always be executed in JavaFX application Thread, so there is no need to wrap them inside `Platform. runLater`.

But when I work with `javafx.concurrent.Task`:

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class BuyTask extends Task<Map<String, Object>> {
    ......
}

BuyTask buyTask = new BuyTask(this.api, params);
Thread buyThread = new Thread(buyTask);
buyThread.start();

buyTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(final WorkerStateEvent workerStateEvent) {
        Map<String, Object> result = (Map) workerStateEvent.getSource().getValue();

        .......

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                portfolioService.restart();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In which thread is the task's event handler executed in? As I need to do `perform restart on a javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService -> portfolioService.restart()` which mentioned must be done in JavaFX Application Thread, I wrap it inside `Platform.runLater`.

But is it required? Will this task event handler always being executed in JavaFX Application Thread as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaFX documentation for [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) has the answer:

> Because the Task is designed for use with JavaFX GUI applications, it ensures that every change to its public properties, as well as change notifications for state, errors, and for event handlers, all occur on the main JavaFX application thread.

So - no, there is no need to wrap the call with `Platform.runLater`.

Comment: @firephil - please read both this question and the examples carefully. This question is about the `onSucceeded` and `onFailed` events, which the `Task` class always calls on the JavaFX UI thread. The examples in the `Task` documentation present changes inside the main logic of the task, not the `onSucceeded` or `onFailed` event handlers.